# Custom Calendar in Android | Java

Tags: java, android, api, date, calendar

How do I create a custom calendar like below preview?
The sundays are shown in red color, dates having events are showed in green where events are coming from API, and current date in blue color.
When clicking on the event date it shows a dialog of the event date coming from api.

[Calendar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDlGw.png)

[Dialog on click of event date Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R8V8.png)

Any help or code would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Some quick search find a lot of samples. Try https://www.google.com/search?q=github+calendar+android&oq=github+calendar+android&aqs=chrome..69i57.4826j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

you can do this on multiple ways. You can check gridview or recyclerview.
[Gridview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView)

Basically android has own calendar structure don't forget it.